# DinkToPdf display on every page

Tags: c#, html, css, pdf, dinktopdf

I want to display a header on every page of the PDF i get with DinkToPdf. I know I can use the HeaderSettings class, but I cannot edit that text (I want to add a background color). Is there any way I can achieve that with html?

I've also tried to set the HtmUrl of the HeaderSettings, but that didn't work.

This is the header I want on every page:

```
.header {
    background-color: #022251;
    color: white;
    padding: 1%;
}
```

Comment: Please show the htmurl try and the code

Answer (score 0):

HtmUrl of the HeaderSettings is the answer for custom Header.

Create a html file and add a class header and add these styles. Now Give absolute path of your html file to htmurl.
Let me know if any issues!